# I want to get document.elements value of HTA running in VBA

Tags: vba

test source

```
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION `enter code here`
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub TestSub
        Msgbox "Testing 1-2-3."
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Run Script" name="run_button" onClick="TestSub"> 
</body>
```

For example

In the running html application (title: HTA Test)

The value of (`name = "run_button"`)
Get with VBA (`document.getelementsby`)

I want to come and ask if this is possible.

Comment: You could just open the HTA as a text file and search for it

Answer (score 0):

Named elements in a HTA file can be referred by their name.

> run_button.value

When more than 1 element share the same name, the name will return a collection of elements.

> run_buttons(1).value

```
<input type="button" value="Run Script" name="run_buttons" onClick="TestSub">
```

```
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION `enter code here`
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub TestSub
        Msgbox run_button.value
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Run Script" name="run_button" onClick="TestSub"> 
</body>
```

Another technique would be to pass a reference of element to the subroutine using `Me`.

```
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION `enter code here`
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub TestSub(ele)
        Msgbox ele.value
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Run Script" name="run_buttons" onClick="TestSub(Me)"> 

</body>
```

When I write HTA or VBS files, I use HTAEdit and Vbsedit respectively.  You can get them here [VBEdit.com](http://www.vbsedit.com/).